# Why is pivot_table an attribute and melt is a function?

Tags: python, pandas

I've just started learning Python and I've got a good knowledge of R,

I've been getting to grips with pandas and have been using melt and pivot_table for a while but there's one thing I don't quite follow...

why is pivot_table an attribute of a DataFrame where melt is a function?

In my mind they are compliments of one another and so they should be of the same type.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hard question why it is implemented this way... Btw, `pivot_table` works both ways -  [`pandas.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html), [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

Answer (score 2):

You raise a good point - there isn't any particular reason *why* `pd.melt` couldn't be a method instead of a top-level function for consistency. That's probably why it is an open issue at the moment, see **[API: add top-level functions as method #12640](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/12640)** on GitHub. It is also worth noting as jezrael pointed out that that the moment `pivot_table` is accessible both as a [top level function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) as well as [a method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html).

Most likely the top-level functions shall be deprecated in favor of the methods on `DataFrame` to enforce some more consistency in an upcoming version.

Comment: Thanks Mitch and jezreal, good to know I'm not missing something fundamental.

Comment: @granddejeuner Good question by the way! I'll update this answer if I see something changes anytime soon.